# F# compilation / deployment

Tags: deployment, f#, compilation

I have a library A which relies on Microsoft Office Excel Interop.

I then have an application B that relies on application A.

How do I set up Visual Studio so I can easily deploy my application ?

I have tried using the --standalone flag in the properties tab. But I end up with several dlls, including FSharp.Core.dll (so it is not "included" in the app), and A.dll

But regardless of whether I use --standalone, there is no Excel interop dll in the app output folder. The problem is: how to deploy the app to make sure that everyone has the Excel interop dll ?

I have tried copy/pasting the dll to the app folder, but to no use...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried adding a reference to the interop DLL in your project's references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to go to the properties of the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` reference in project A in the Solution Explorer and set "Copy Local" to **True**.

Then the build process of B should automatically copy through the interop libraries referenced in A. I think this should work with `--standalone` as well, but I have not tested that.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was more linked to an excel version difference between our computers. The copy-local was necessary however, hence the check. Thanks a lot for your help.